# iOS のアプリは暗号化されているらしいのですが、それはどのような機構で実現されているのでしょうか?

Tags: ios, security

モバイルアプリのセキュリティについて調べていく過程で、 https://stackoverflow.com/a/5557283/3090068 のような記事を何回か見掛けたりします。どういうことかというと、 iOS において、配布されているアプリは暗号化されている、という趣旨の記述です。

## 質問

iOS アプリが仮に暗号化されているとして、それはどのタイミングで、誰が、何を、どのように暗号化しているのでしょうか?セキュリティについて考えるのであるならば、どのような全体的な仕組みでこれが実現されているのかを理解することが重要であると考えており、しかしこれが分かるように書かれているソースなどを発見できていないので、質問しています。

Comment: FWIW: Appleフォーラムで[Apple staffが投稿した内容](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/717128)によると、「iOSとApp Store間でのみ必要となるやり取りであるため文書化されていない」ようです。（回答になるかわからないので、コメントまで）